# Android image Background in Holo Theme

Tags: android, image, background, android-activity, themes

I saw this thing that has been treated several times, but I found no answer that makes for me.
In my app I use the Holo theme, and now I want to display a background image to full screen in all activities.

I put this line:
`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

<item name="android:background">@drawable/sfondo1</item>`

in the file style.xml and I have this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"
    >
```

in the Manifest, but it does not work.

Comment: Create a new theme, paste Holo properties and add your background inside... Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in your manifest file

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
```

instead of

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo"
>
```